# discord.py: How to get the first letter of a user's name?

Tags: python, string, discord.py

I want to make a "ticket-system" and want the channel it creates to have the name of the first letter of the user. So, I already have this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(reaction):
ticket = await guildbtv.create_text_channel(name=f'ticket', overwrites=overwrites, category=supportcat,
                                                    position=None, topic='Hier kannst du dein Anliegen äussern!',
                                           reason='Ticket')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the name of the user by using `client.get_user(ID).display_name`

Getting the first letter of the nickname of the user in the guild that reacted in:

```py
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    first_letter = user.display_name[0]
```

Getting the first letter of the username of the user:

```py
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    first_letter = client.get_user(user.id).display_name[0]
```